# Double value returns 0

Tags: java, division

Here's an example:

```
Double d = (1/3);
System.out.println(d);
```

This returns 0, not 0.33333... as it should.

Does anyone know?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It isn't a duplicate. That question is a duplicate of this question. Look at the dates before you flag

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's because `1` and `3` are treated as `integers` when you don't specify otherwise, so `1/3` evaluates to the `integer` `0` which is then cast to the `double` `0`. To fix it, try `(1.0/3)`, or maybe `1D/3` to explicitly state that you're dealing with double values.

Answer (score 13):

If you have `int`s that you want to divide using floating-point division, you'll have to cast the `int` to a `double`:

```
double d = (double)intValue1 / (double)intValue2
```

(Actually, only casting `intValue2` should be enough to have the `intValue1` be casted to `double` automatically, I believe.)

Answer (score 1):

Use **double** and not **Double** unless you need to use these values in the object sense. Be aware about the [Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) concepts

Comment: The OP was asking about Java's truncation methods and why a division of integers is truncated, even if stored in a double; not about autoboxing.